# The problem is in the text of different programs

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, text, fonts

When I open unity hub or other programs that have a similar interface, the letters become blurry, and when I hover over one or another text, it becomes normal. That is, the problem is not specifically in the Unity Hub because it happens in some other programs as well.

I suspect that the problem is in Windows, that there is some function that does this.

[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5hQv.gif)

[this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x36Sn.png)

[this is what it looks like2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNqEW.png)